# Server doesn't receive iOS POST

Tags: php, ios, xcode

For hours I try to send post data from my iOS app to a server.
I recently changed the server and now the code doesn't work anymore - so I would say its the 'fault' of the new server im using. (I changed the server because the old one couldn't work with the traffic).
But i'm not sure, so I just wanna ask if something with my code is wrong, or could be fault.
Maybe you have an idea (I googled and stackoverflowed for hours now :/ )

The code I use is:

```
    NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"udid=%@&message=%@",UUID,field.text];

    NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.de/file.php"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Data: %@",data);
```

As I said it did work on the other server, so maybe I have to change some encoding or something like that?

Comment: is data anything? is the error value set? Please log these things to help us out. Otherwise we can't tell if there is an error or not.

Comment: if I put the data and error out, I just receive nothing. In the last line its NSlog(@"Data: %@",data); - it just outputs "Data: " in the console. No errors.

Comment: Does your new server have mod_security or a firewall configured differently from your old server?  That's what I have my money on.

Comment: With my "hobby-dev"-eyes I checked the phpinfo and don't really see a difference. Maybe it would help if I post the phpinfo here?

Comment: Oh btw, it is always useful to initialise error to nil, because if no error occurs then it is never set, so you cannot compare it to nil to check for no error, if that makes sense.